# How to handle correctly sparse features to avoid poor performance of classification neural network?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to understand how sparse neural networks work. I have a very sparse data of about 40k rows for two classes. The dataset looks like this:

```
    RA0 RA1 RA2 RA3 RA4 RA5 RA6 RA7 RA8 RA9 RB0 RB1 RB2 RB3 RB4 RB5 RB6 RB7 RB8 RB9
50  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
51  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
52  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
53  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
54  0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
55  1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
56  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
57  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
58  1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
59  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
60  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
61  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
62  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
63  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

As you can see, some rows have only 0's on it. The columns with name `RA` are the features of a `class 0` and the columns with name `RB` are the features of `class 1`, so the same dataset with the actual `labels` looks like this:

```
    RA0 RA1 RA2 RA3 RA4 RA5 RA6 RA7 RA8 RA9 ... RB1 RB2 RB3 RB4 RB5 RB6 RB7 RB8 RB9 label
50  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
51  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
52  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
53  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
54  0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
55  1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
56  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
57  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
58  1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
59  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
60  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
```

I did a simple neural network model using `Keras`, but the model isn't learning and accuracy rarely goes beyond 52% on train dataset. I tried two variations of the same model:

Variation 1:

```
def build_nn(n_features,lr = 0.001):
    _input = Input(shape = (n_features,),name = 'input',sparse = True)
    x = Dense(12,kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform',activation = 'relu')(_input)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Dense(8,kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform',activation = 'relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Dense(2,kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform',activation = 'softmax')(x)
    nn = Model(inputs = [_input],outputs = [x])
    nn.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=Adam(lr = lr),metrics=['accuracy'])
    return nn
```

Variation 2:

```
def build_nn(feature_layer,lr = 0.001):
    feature_inputs = {}
    for feature in feature_layer:
        feature_inputs[feature.key] = Input(shape = (1,),name = feature.key)
    feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_layer)
    feature_inputs_n = feature_layer(feature_inputs)
    x = Dense(12,kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform',activation = 'relu')(feature_inputs_n)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Dense(8,kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform',activation = 'relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Dense(2,kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform',activation = 'softmax')(x)
    nn = Model(inputs = [v for v in feature_inputs.values()],outputs = [x])
    nn.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=Adam(lr = lr),metrics=['accuracy'])
    return nn
```

The motivation behind doing the variation 2 is because the features are sparse and I thought that this could have an impact on the model's performance, so I followed [this tensorflow guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/sparse_tensor).

Also, the labels are converted to a categorical label using `to_categorical` function, provided by the keras api:

```
y_train2 = to_categorical(y_train)
y_test2 = to_categorical(y_test)
```

My questions are:

1. Is my model wrong (especially the variation 2) or if I'm doing the wrong representation of the sparse features and how this features should be handled?
2. The `RA` and `RB` are the features of two different classes and since there are rows full of 0, should I add a third class representing an unknown class or remove the rows that contains only 0?
3. Since `RA` and `RB` map two different classes, should I do two separate model, one for columns `RA` and class 0 and the other for columns `RB` and class 1?

I'm also posting an image of the train/test model's accuracy:

[image: model's accuracy]

I can also provide any other part of the code if needed.

EDIT:
I didn't put this part because I felt it doesn't has a relation to what I was asking, but it seems I was wrong.

Each feature is an individual branch from a sklearn decision tree. The class that the `decision tree` looks for is an up or down for the next candle in a trading enviroment (a candle is a price aggregation of an instrument in time that has an open, low, high and close price). Then, the idea is to grab those branches, that are valuated in the price time series, and evaluate if the condition is met, so if the branch is active the value is 1.

For example, branch `RA0` at index 55 is active, so the value is `1`. The labels are calculated as `np.sign(close - open)`. So, the idea is that by using multiple branches the classification of the label can be improved, by having a neural network that can see if which branch is active and which one has more weight in order to make a classification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` is wrong here; the sparsity in `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` refers to the *label representation*, and not to the features. Since you are using one-hot encoded labels:

```
y_train2 = to_categorical(y_train)
y_test2 = to_categorical(y_test)
```

and a final layer of 2 nodes with `activation = 'softmax'` (which I take it to mean that you have only 2 classes), you should switch to `loss='categorical_crossentropy'` irrespectively of the sparsity in your *features*.

Other general remarks:

- **Remove dropout**, which should *never* be used by default. Dropout is used to help against overfitting *if* such a thing is detected; used uncritically (even worse, with such high values), it is well-known to prevent training altogether (i.e. something very similar to what you report here).
- Remove `kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform'` from all layers, thus leaving the [default](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/dense/) `glorot_uniform` one (useful hint: **default values are there for a reason**, and it is not advisable to play with them unless you have a *specific* reason to do so and you know exactly what you are doing).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try your suggestions. Regarding the training data, should I remove all rows that has only 0 values?

Comment: @xerac difficult to say w/o the problem context (and the *labels* of such rows).

Comment: Each feature is the result of a branch extracted from a decision tree. So, basically when calculating the feature its something like `data['RA0'] = eval(branch[0])` (the branch from the decision tree is strored as a string). All branches are related to class 0 or class 1 (RA related to class 0 and RB related to class one). The thing is that each branch alone is somewhat good, but what I was aiming for is that maybe some branches in combination with other branches are better than the branch alone.

Comment: @xerac all this may sound clear in your head, but believe me, it doesn't sound like that in anyone else's head (including mine). Plus, such info, if considered useful for the problem, should be part of the question and not a comment. Here at SO we can help you on the *programming* aspects of your issue, but regarding your specific problem context (as already asked, what about the *labels*?) and data (which we don't have), you are more or less on your own, and experiment is king.

Comment: I understand that in my head it is "clear". In order to provide context, I added an edit explaining where the features come from and the intended use.

Comment: @xerac did you try the suggestions in the answer? Were they helpful?

Comment: I did tried your suggestions, but the results weren't improved. Actually, it seems that the model is overfitting with the increase in epochs, because the accuracy in train is increasing but the accuracy in test data gets stucked at ~51% (this was the max value achieved). On the other hand, I dont know if this can be called actually overfitting, beacuse the train accuracy converges to around a 53% :(